# How to place a plugin block to twig template without any contributed module?

Tags: 8, blocks, plugins

I am using Drupal 8. Have created a custom module, added custom block "LskyTestVideo", created a new page template with its own controller ("LskyOpenTokTestController"). In LskyOpenTokTestController::index action I rendered test-video-page.html.twig . Inside this page I need to place LskyTestVideo block.Here my code:

```
class LskyOpenTokTestController extends ControllerBase {

public function index() {
$block_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');

$config = [];
$plugin_block = $block_manager->createInstance('lsky_test_video', $config);

$access_result = $plugin_block->access(\Drupal::currentUser());

if (is_object($access_result) && $access_result->isForbidden() || is_bool($access_result) && 
!$access_result) {
  return [];
}
$render = $plugin_block->build();

return [
  '#theme' => 'open_tok_test_video_page',
  '#attached' => [
    'library' => [
      'lsky_open_tok/video-test-window',
      'lsky_open_tok/opentok',
    ],
  ],
  '#test' => $render,
];
 }

}
```

Here test-video.html.twig

```
    <div class="test-video-block">{{ test }}</div>
```

When the page is rendered, it returns 0.
How I can place a custom plugin block inside twig template. Thanks.

Comment: You say you don't want to use any contrib module, but I say [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and then it's just `{{ drupal_block('plugin_id') }}`. See [Rendering blocks with Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak). And see Twig Tweak's [cheat sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet).

Comment: What happens if you render your custom block through block layout? Does it render the expected content?

Comment: Thanks for answers. Through the block layout, it works fine. But I need markup customization.

Comment: This could be achieved easily by extending block.html.twig.